# connecting 4 wire camera to esp8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, electronics

I am looking for the arduino code to stream video to a webpage using the ESP8266.
here is the 4 wire camera I have: https://www.ebay.com/itm/172272466793

The other tutorials I'm finding online are all for a different cameras or are not using the ESP8266 for webpage streaming.

Any help or pointers would be most appreciated.

- As a side note I have LiFePo 3.3v batteries that I plan to use to power both the ESP8266 and the 5v camera (by wiring them in series). 
  The thing I am completely lost on is how to wire the video and audio to ports and access them with arduino code.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE. Please realize that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway.

Comment: Google first, ask latter. This had been asked several times in Arduino SE.

Comment: Questions may not rely on external links for basic information.  "Four wire camera" does not capture the key fact that this is an analog NTSC camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Your link is to an *analog* NTSC camera.   Digitally handling data from this would require a high speed analog to digital converter and some fairly sophisticated cleanup logic.

It is simply not compatible to use this with a small embedded system.

If you really want a camera for a resource constrained embedded system, seek a *still* camera with a serial or SPI output.

Most video tasks will however be better done on more capable embedded systems falling outside the realm of Arduino-style approaches, and therefore soundly off-topic here.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly if I can find a digital camera with a serial output then it would be compatible for the esp8266?

Comment: Yes but it's likely a terribly bad idea as a project.